# What is Integration Testing and How It is Performed?

Tags: php, testing

We have studied about various Software developments lifecycle models. All the SDLC models have Integration testing as one of the layers. In my opinion, Integration testing is actually a “level” of testing rather than a “Type” of testing. i am right ?

Answer (score 3):

When individual software modules are merged and tested as a group than it is known as integration testing. Integration testing is sets between Unit Testing and System Testing.

Integration Testing Example

For example you have to test the keyboard of a computer than it is a unit testing but when you have to combine the keyboard and mouse of a computer together to see its working or not than it is the integration testing. So it is prerequisite that for performing integration testing a system must be unit tested before.

Black-box test case design tactics are the most typical during integration, although limited amount of testing of white box may be used to ensure description of major control paths.

What is Integration Testing?

Integration testing is executed to establish whether the components interact with each other consort to the specification or not. Integration testing in large refers to joining all the components resulting in the complete system. It is further performed by the developer or the software Tester or by both. Example- checking that a Payroll system interacts as required with the Human Resource system.

Integration testing is always sub-divided as follows:
Types of Integration Testing

1) Top-Down Integration Testing: Top Down Integration as the term suggests, starts always at the top of the program hierarchy and travels towards its branches. This can be done in either depth-first or breadth-first.

2) Bottom-Up Integration Testing: Bottom –Up integration as it name implies starts at the lowest level in the program structure.

Some Techniques of integration testing: Techniques of integration testing can be given below

1) Top-down testing approach
2) Bottom-up testing approach
3) Big-Bang testing approach
4) Sandwiched testing approach

Conclusion: At last we conclude that Integration testing focuses on testing multiple modules working together.

Integration testing (sometimes called the Integration and Testing, abbreviated as I and T) is one of the extensive exercises of the software testing in which particular software modules are merged and tested as a group.